# Date Time Conversions in PySpark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, azure-databricks, unix-timestamp, epoch

Can someone please explain me how the below epoch time

- epoch time/unix-timestamp :**1668443121840**
- converts to the date : **2022-11-14T16:25:21.840+0000**

How is the conversion taking place and additionally how to identify an epoch timestamp if it is mentioned in seconds, milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds?

Additionally, is there a function in pyspark to convert the date back to epoch timestamp?

Thanks! in advance.

I tried a number of methods but I am not achieving the expected result:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-11-12 02:12:23', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(t.strftime('%s'))
```

As I am not able to control the format or accuracy in terms of seconds, milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The epoch time/unix-timestamp uses a reference date: 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970. It counts the seconds/milliseconds from that date.

The value you are looking for is in miliseconds, so you would have to calculate the milliseconds and concatenate with the epoch time:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2022-11-14T16:25:21.840+0000',)]).toDF("timestamp")\


df\
.withColumn("timestamp",F.to_timestamp(F.col("timestamp")))\
.withColumn("epoch_seconds",F.unix_timestamp("timestamp"))\
.withColumn("epoch_miliseconds",F.concat(F.unix_timestamp("timestamp"), F.date_format("timestamp", "S")))\
.show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
# |timestamp             |epoch_seconds|epoch_miliseconds|
# +----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
# |2022-11-14 16:25:21.84|1668443121   |16684431218      |
# +----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) counts the seconds that have elapsed since **00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970**.

To convert dates to unix-timestamp in PySpark, you can use the [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html) function.